# Can a computable program have an infinite output?

Tags: computability

Can a computable program produce an infinite output from its (presumably finite) input?

*I wouldn't think so for similar argument as to why it can't compute over an infinite input.

A follow on (basically the same?) question: Are there non-halting programs that are computable?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "computable program"?  Can you give a definition?

Comment: computable by a Turing machine or equivalent model of computation

Answer (score 2):

Our general rule is one question per post.  I'll answer the first question.

A program can certainly produce infinite output.  It can enter an infinite loop producing output.  Consider everyone's first program in Basic:

```
10 PRINT "Hello World!"
20 GOTO 10
```

It makes no sense to talk about a program being computable.  There's no need to you write a program to output a program.  Instead, you can just write the program you want in the first place.  Instead of talking about computable programs, computability is about languages.  We talk about languages being computable.  Check the definition of computability.