# how is the set of undecidable programs related to the set of non-halting programs?

Tags: undecidability, halting-problem

Is there a non-halting program for every undecidable program? is undecidable the "same thing" as non-halting?

Thanks!

Comment: What is an "undecidable program" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

The notion of an "undecidable program" doesn't make sense, for the [same reasons I gave in response to your last question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/119694/755).  It makes sense to talk about whether a language is decidable or undecidable.  It doesn't make sense to talk about whether a program is decidable or undecidable.  If you check the [formal definition of decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language), you'll see that decidability is only defined for languages.

Undecidable is not the same as non-halting.  Check the definition.